# Accessdatabase engine 2016 gets corrupted frequently on Windows 10 Operating System and ODBC Connection is not able to open excel 2016 driver issue

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am using ODBC Connection to Excel 2016 in c# Visual Studio 2017. I downloaded Microsoft Access database engine redistributable to Windows 10 Operating System in which Office 2016 64 bit is already loaded. But my exe fails frequently corrupting the drivers in odbc connection open. I have to reinstall Microsoft Access database engine every time. Kindly let me know the solution for this problem.

```
public DataTable ConvertExcelToDataTable(string FileName, string sheetName)
{
    DataTable dtResult = null;
    int totalSheet = 0; //No of sheets on excel file              

    using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;text;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text';"))
    {
        objConn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        if (dt != null)
        {
            var tempDataTable = (from dataRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                 where !dataRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase")
                                 select dataRow).CopyToDataTable();
            dt = tempDataTable;
            totalSheet = dt.Rows.Count;
            // sheetName = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        }

        cmd.Connection = objConn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
        // dtResult.Rows.Add(new System.Data.DataRows("NodeID"));

        oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        oleda.Fill(ds, "Data");
        DataRow rowDel = ds.Tables["Data"].Rows[0];
        int ctr = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables["Data"].Columns)
        {
            string val = rowDel[ctr].ToString();
            if (val == string.Empty)
                break;
            dc.ColumnName = val;
            ctr++;
        }
        ds.Tables["Data"].Rows.Remove(rowDel);
        dtResult = ds.Tables["Data"];
        DataTable dtCloned = dtResult.Clone();
        dtCloned.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(string);
        dtCloned.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(string);
        foreach (DataRow row in dtResult.Rows)
        {
            dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
        }

        objConn.Close();

        return dtCloned; //Returning Dattable  
    }
}
```

> UnhandledException:System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected Memory.This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt
>   at System.Data.Oledb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(OledbConnection String,SessionWrapper&

Comment: Unfortunately this error can be caused by many issues. The fist thing I would do is make sure that everything involved is either 32 or 64 bit. Do not use any cpu option.Also posting a stack trace may help us assist you in tracking down the issue.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow; you've provided some useful info, but you've also left out a lot; we need to know what debugging you have already done -- in particular, what debugging tells you that the code you've provided is the code corrupting the drivers?  if you make this function a no-op, does the problem go away?  if not, your problem lies elsewhere, but if so, if you add code back in a little a a time, at what point does it break?  help us help you narrow it down by showing us what you've done